# How to catch PHP snmpwalk warning?

Tags: php, error-handling, snmp, nagios

With Nagios, I have an active and standby server setup I am trying to monitor. When the active is online, it'll respond to this OID. The standby will not answer this OID, however I still want to poll it frequently. This way if the servers flip/flop their status, the SNMP checks will continue to work.

I am configuring both servers in Nagios for routine checks. My goal is to check the standby, and if it times out, then to check the active (defined by variable $peer) to verify the standby is correctly the standby. Then exit with an OK. If the standby AND active don't reply, then exit Critical.

PHP snmpwalk sends a Warning when it times out and can't reach the host. I'm using a custom error handler to catch the warning and do something about it.

I can't seem to fire off the 2nd round of SNMP check though. It goes right past and onto the rest of my script, echoing all my debugs along the way. My expected result was to exit.

How can I do nested try and catch's with this setup?

```
// First, setup error handling. 
function errorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    throw new Exception($errstr, $errno);
}
set_error_handler('errorHandler');

if (!is_null($peer)) { 
    //Dummy SNMP check to see if we get a timeout error or not. 
    try {
        echo "trying ".$host." \n";
        snmpwalk($host,$community,$oid);
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        // If we get here, it timed out. Now check to see if the peer server is up.
        echo "timed out, trying ".$peer." \n";
        try {
            snmpwalk($peer,$community,$oid);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            // At this point, the peer server is up, so chances are we're the standby.
            echo "standby is up, we are ok";
            $output = "OK: It appears this is the standby server. \n"; 
            fwrite(STDOUT, $output);
            exit(0);
        }
    echo "Hmm, something else happened. \n";
    }
}

// Restore default error handler. 
restore_error_handler();
```

Comment: Does it hit the 2nd catch block or just echo 'Hmm, something else happened'? If the latter, then your 2nd snmpwalk call worked fine. Also - there is a return value from snmpwalk you can use - if false, an error occurred.

Comment: It echo's "timed out, trying peer"... then echos "hmm something else happened". Perhaps you're right. Since the peer didn't fail, it didn't go to the last exception.  I tried looking for the snmpwalk return value, but couldn't find it. I wasn't sure if there was an easier way to simplify this sort of check.

Comment: Well different behaviour is presumably because of the different values - $peer and $host. Change your 2nd snmpwalk to use $host again to see if your try/catch works then.

Comment: I think you clued me in correctly. I moved my OK to the "hmm something has happened". Then put in a "All servers down" in the 2nd exception and its appears to be working on the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your catch block includes comments indicating you think you succeeded in connecting to $peer but the catch block will only run if it FAILS to connect to $peer.

Move your code outside the catch block and you will get the behaviour you desire.